# Speed up assembling matrix by interleaving vectors?

Tags: performance, r, matrix

I have two vectors of arbitrary and equal length

```
a <- c(0.8,0.8,0.8) 
b <- c(0.4,0.4,0.4)
n <- length(a)
```

From these I need to assemble an `2n` by `2n` matrix of the form:

```
x = [1-a1  b1    1-a2  b2    1-a3  b3
     a1    1-b1  a2    1-b2  a3    1-b3
     1-a1  b1    1-a2  b2    1-a3  b3
     a1    1-b1  a2    1-b2  a3    1-b3
     1-a1  b1    1-a2  b2    1-a3  b3
     a1    1-b1  a2    1-b2  a3    1-b3]
```

I currently do this using

```
x <- matrix(rep(as.vector(rbind(
                          c(1-a,a), 
                          c(b, 1-b))),
                n),
            ncol=n*2, byrow=TRUE)
```

How can I speed up this operation? Profiling indicates that `matrix` is taking the most time:

```
Rprof("out.prof")
for (i in 1:100000) {

x <- matrix(rep(as.vector(rbind(
  c(1-a,a), 
  c(b, 1-b))),
                n),
            ncol=n*2, byrow=TRUE)

}
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("out.prof")

##$by.self
##            self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
##"matrix"         1.02    63.75       1.60    100.00
##"rbind"          0.24    15.00       0.36     22.50
##"as.vector"      0.18    11.25       0.54     33.75
##"c"              0.10     6.25       0.10      6.25
##"*"              0.04     2.50       0.04      2.50
##"-"              0.02     1.25       0.02      1.25
##
##$by.total
##            total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
##"matrix"          1.60    100.00      1.02    63.75
##"as.vector"       0.54     33.75      0.18    11.25
##"rbind"           0.36     22.50      0.24    15.00
##"c"               0.10      6.25      0.10     6.25
##"*"               0.04      2.50      0.04     2.50
##"-"               0.02      1.25      0.02     1.25
##
##$sample.interval
##[1] 0.02
##
##$sampling.time
##[1] 1.6
```

Comment: Can we assume that all elements of `a` are equal to one another and that all elements of `b` are equal to one another?

Comment: No, the elements of `a` and `b` are not always equal.  Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Whoops.  Should be `n`.  Fixing.

Comment: Can I also assume that you actually care about performance on much bigger matrices, or is `n == 3` an important use case for you?

Comment: In general, the number of elements is small (`n` is 2-20), but the operation is repeated many times.

Comment: How do `a` and `b` vary? If there's a small set of possibilities you could easily cache the results.  It only takes ~8 microseconds to create the matrix, which is already pretty fast.

Comment: `a` and `b` change in almost every iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an alternative to `matrix` being the slowest part of your profile, but you can definitely save a little time by optimizing the rest. For example:

```
x <- matrix(rbind(c(1-a,a), c(b, 1-b)), 2*n, 2*n, byrow=TRUE)
```

Also, although I would not recommend it, you can save a little extra time by using the Internal matrix function:

```
x <- .Internal(matrix(rbind(c(1-a,a), c(b, 1-b)),
                      n*2, n*2, TRUE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE))
```

Here are some benchmarks:

```
benchmark(
   method0 = matrix(rep(as.vector(rbind(c(1-a,a), c(b, 1-b))), n),
                    ncol=n*2, byrow=TRUE),
   method1 = matrix(rbind(c(1-a,a), c(b, 1-b)), 2*n, 2*n, byrow=TRUE),
   method2 = .Internal(matrix(rbind(c(1-a,a), c(b, 1-b)),
                              n*2, n*2, TRUE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE)),
   replications = 100000,
   order = "relative")

#      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 3 method2       100000    1.00     1.00      0.99        0         NA        NA
# 2 method1       100000    1.13     1.13      1.12        0         NA        NA
# 1 method0       100000    1.46     1.46      1.46        0         NA        NA
```

Comment: Note that you can't use `.Internal` in packages hosted on CRAN.  See the [CRAN Repository Policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html).

Comment: That's in part why I said I would not recommend it. My biggest concern would be that the R developers are free to make changes to these internals, and it could cause this code to break in the future.

Comment: Yes, I figured that was the reason. I just wanted to be explicit. ;)

Comment: I get some extra speeding by compiling the function using `compiler::cmpfun()`.  Not as much as using .Internal, but better.

Answer (score 0):

I get a small speedup with the following:

```
f = function(a, b, n){
  z = rbind(
    c(rbind(1 - a, b)),
    c(rbind(a, 1 - b))
  )

  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:n, function(i) z))
}
```

I'll keep looking.

**Edit** I'm stumped. If this isn't good enough, I'd recommend inlining some rcpp.

Comment: On my machine, this is almost twice as slow as the OP's version.

Comment: Weird.  On my machine, `system.time(replicate(100000, f(a, b, n)))` takes 2 seconds and `system.time(replicate(100000, g(a, b, n)))` takes 3.5, where g is what Noam wrote.

Comment: Yours takes less than a second, though. Nice optimization.